# > Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be three independent uniform random variables on $[0, 1]$. What is $P(XY < Z^2)$?

Tags: probability

> Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be three independent uniform random variables on $[0, 1]$. Compute the probability $P(XY < Z^2)$.

I used the following approach :

Step 1 : Calculated the Probability distribution for $XY$. It turns out to be $P(XY \leq K) = \frac 1K$.

Step 2 : Calculated the Probability distribution for $Z^2$. It turns out to be $P(Z^2 \leq L) = P(-\root \of{L} \leq Z \leq \root \of{L}) = \root \of{L}$.

Step 3: Calculate the joint density function by multiplying the above functions and differentiating. I get $$f_{Q_1Q_2} (q_1,q_2) = \frac {-1}{2q_1^2\root\of{q_2}}$$. where $Q_1 = XY$ , $Q_2 =Z^2$.

Step 4: Calculate the probability using the integral below. 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{q_1}^{1}\frac{-1}{2q_1^2\root\of{q_2}}dq_2dq_1$$

There is definitely something wrong with this procedure. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904421/let-x-y-and-z-be-three-independent-uniform-random-variables-on-0-1

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/185501/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the CDF of $XY$ is not correct.

\begin{align}
P(XY \le K) &= 1-P(XY >K)\\
&= 1- \int_{K}^1\int_{\frac{K}{x}}^1 \, dy\, dx \\
&= 1-\int_K^1 (1-\frac{K}{x}) \, dx\\
&= 1-[x-K\ln x]_K^1 \\
&= 1-(1-K+K\ln K) \\
&= K - K \ln K
\end{align}

Note that density can't be negative in step $3$.

$$f_{Q_1,Q_2}(q_1, q_2)=\frac{-\ln q_1}{2\sqrt{q_2}}$$

\begin{align}&\int_0^1\int_{q_1}^1 -\frac{\ln q_1}{2\sqrt{q_2}}\, dq_2\, dq_1 = \frac59 \end{align}

Edit to check your integral:

\begin{align}
P(XY \le K) &= \int_K^1 \int_0^{\frac{K}{x}}\, dy \, dx + \int_0^K\int_0^1 \, dy \, dx\\
&=\int_K^1 \frac{K}{x}\, dx + K\\
&=K\ln x|_K^1+K\\
&=K-K\ln K
\end{align}

Comment: +1 for the answer! $P(XY \leq K) = \int_{K}^1\int^{\frac{K}{x}}_0 \, dy\, dx +\int_{0}^K\int^{1}_0 \, dy\, dx$  Is this the same thing you wrote?

Comment: It looks the same to me, just different way of describing the region. I describe the complement as it can be easily described in a single intergral.

Comment: But evaluating this integral I get the value I describe in the question. The first part is -K + 1\K and the second integral is K

Comment: Hi,  I included my working for that integral. Perhaps you might like to check to see if you can spot the mistake?

Comment: Oh my my . I feel stupid now. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Alternative (avoiding calculation of CDF's and PDF's):
$$\begin{aligned}P\left(XY\leq Z^{2}\right) & =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\left[xy\leq z^{2}\right]dzdxdy\\
 & =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}1-x^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{2}}dxdy\\
 & =1-\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\frac{1}{2}}y^{\frac{1}{2}}dxdy\\
 & =1-\int_{0}^{1}y^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\frac{1}{2}}dxdy\\
 & =1-\int_{0}^{1}x^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\times\int_{0}^{1}y^{\frac{1}{2}}xdy\\
 & =1-\left(\int_{0}^{1}x^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\right)^{2}\\
 & =1-\left(\left[\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{0}^{1}\right)^{2}\\
 & =1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2}\\
 & =\frac{5}{9}
\end{aligned}
$$

Here $\left[xy\leq z^{2}\right]$ denotes the function $[0,1]^3\to\mathbb R$ that takes value $1$ if $xy\leq z^{2}$ and takes value $0$ otherwise.

Comment: +1 Wow, I think I'm new to this. How do you get the equality in the first step? :P

Comment: The first step is based on $P(XY\leq Z^2)=\mathbb E\mathbf1_{XY\leq Z^2}$

Comment: To make things more clear: if $f(x,y,z)=1$ if $xy\leq z^2$ and $f(x,y,z)=0$ otherwise then $P(XY\leq Z^2)=\mathbb Ef(X,Y,Z)$. That is applied here.

Answer (score 1):

from [Does the square of uniform distribution have density function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305997/does-the-square-of-uniform-distribution-have-density-function)
we know that $Z\sim U[0,1] => f_{Z^2}(t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}$

and from here [product distribution of two uniform distribution, what about 3 or more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659254/product-distribution-of-two-uniform-distribution-what-about-3-or-more)
we know that $X\sim U[0,1],Y\sim U[0,1]\,iid => F_{XY}(t) = t-t\log t$

from [Finding probability $P(X<Y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261073/finding-probability-pxy)
we know that $P(X<Y) = \int F_X(t) f_Y(t)dt$

$$P(XY<Z^2) = \int_0^1P(XY<t)f_{Z^2}(t)dt 
= \int_0^1(t - t\log(t))\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \sqrt{t} - \sqrt{t}\log t\,dt = (\frac{5}{9} t^{3/2} - t^{3/2} \log t) |_0^1 = \frac{5}{9}$$

Comment: +1 for the answer!