# Intuition of the relation between poisson process and order statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Lemma: Let $T_n$ be the time of the nth arrival in a Poisson process and $U_k$, $k=1,2....n$ be independent uniform on $(0,1)$. Then the order statistics of $U_1, U_2,....,U_n$ have the same distribution of $(T_1/T_{N+1},T_2/T_{N+1},...,T_N/T_{N+1})$.

I could prove the lemma by simply find out the joint density of the above vector which is $n!$ for both case. However, I would like to know is there any intuition that I could understand the lemma without directly calculate the answer.

I have read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74218/relations-between-order-statistics-of-uniform-rvs-and-exponential-rvs), but I think that it may be unrelated to the problem, though not for sure.

Comment: Your linked question is effectively the same with $Y_j=T_j-T_{j-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intuition:

- Consider a radioactive source of particles treated as producing particles in a Poisson process
- Conditioning on the $n+1$ particle being emitted at time $t_{n+1}$, the previous $n$ earlier particles can each have been emitted at any time in the interval $[0,t_{n+1}]$
- Ignoring order, the emission time of each of the $n$ earlier particles has an  independent uniform distribution time in that interval, as the cause of each emission is independent of the others
- Hence the two equivalent distributions in the question